# Linear Algebra Complex values

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> The cube roots of $-3+2i$ are $x_1 = (1.0106+1.1532i),\; x_2 = (0.4934-1.4519i),\text{ and }x_3 = (-1.5040+bi)$
>   What is $b$?

So $$-3+2i = (x_1)(x_2)(x_3) = -3.268 + 2.172bi + 1.351i + 0.898b$$

$$-3+2i - 1.351i = -3.268 + 2.172bi + 0.898b$$

$$-3+0.649i +3.268 = 2.172bi + 0.898b$$

$$0.268 + 0.649i = 2.172bi + 0.898b$$

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: My guess is that there is a $b$ such that $0.649i = 2.172bi$ and $0.268 = 0.898b$. I haven't worked with the numbers myself, however, and I can't be sure. **N.B.:** these seem to be floating point numbers, and the precision may have been lost.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there! :)

Since two complex numbers are equal iff their real and imaginary parts are equal, we know that:

$$0.268 = 0.898b\qquad 0.649 = 2.172b$$

But, we are dealing with rounded-off values.  This means it is reasonable to expect that the two equations above may give slightly different answers.

We find that the first equation gives $\approx0.298$, and the second gives $\approx 0.298$.